# About adding series in TableXYDataset

Tags: java, jfreechart

I am using `ChartFactory.createStackedXYAreaChart()` in my application using `JFreeChart`. 
This chart needs `TableXYDataset` in it's argument at the time of creation. My problem is that I am using different series to add in charts, but it does not allow me to add differant series to the `XYDataset`.  I am using the following code:

```
XYSeries series1 = new XYSeries("First");

series1.add(0.1,25);
series1.add(0.2,43);
series1.add(0.5,70);
series1.add(0.64,94);
series1.add(0.9,112);

XYSeries series2 = new XYSeries("Second");

series2.add(0.9,112);
series2.add(1.1,150);
series2.add(1.3,175);
series2.add(1.5,200);
series2.add(1.7,225);
series2.add(1.9,250);

XYSeriesCollection dataset = new XYSeriesCollection();
dataset.addSeries(series1);
dataset.addSeries(series2);

return dataset;
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`DefaultTableXYDataset`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/xy/DefaultTableXYDataset.html) is a `TableXYDataset` that has an `addSeries(XYSeries series)` method.

Addendum: Note that duplicates are *not* allowed. For example,

[image]

```
XYSeries series1 = new XYSeries("First", true, false);
series1.add(0.1, 25);
series1.add(0.2, 43);
series1.add(0.5, 70);
series1.add(0.64, 94);
series1.add(0.9, 112);

XYSeries series2 = new XYSeries("Second", true, false);
series2.add(0.9, 112);
series2.add(1.1, 150);
series2.add(1.3, 175);
series2.add(1.5, 200);
series2.add(1.7, 225);
series2.add(1.9, 250);

DefaultTableXYDataset dataset = new DefaultTableXYDataset();
dataset.addSeries(series1);
dataset.addSeries(series2);
return dataset;
```

Comment: trashgod:: Thanks buddy..! In the same graph I am using value marker to show domain axis value.. the cade I am using  for it is Marker myDateMarker = new ValueMarker(new Double(0.31));
  myDateMarker.setPaint(Color.BLACK); plot.addDomainMarker(myDateMarker);
  plot.addDomainMarker(myDateMarker, Layer.FOREGROUND);
  myDateMarker.setStroke(new BasicStroke(0.6f));     I want to set the marker as dotted.. how should I do ??

Comment: Thanks for help.. in the same application i want to add the the errorlines (range error lines).. I am using XYDataset.. can anyone post me the code specifying hw to add these error lines? I am using the scatter chart gor it

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but this sounds like a new question. You might browse the [API, samples or guide](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/) for related examples, e.g. `CandlestickRenderer`.

Comment: trashgod: I mean to say i want to add error bars at points in scatter plot..can u post related code for it?

Comment: [`XYErrorRenderer`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/renderer/xy/XYErrorRenderer.html) looks promising, although I've not used it.

Comment: trashgod: HI.. yea, actually this XYRenderer provides such facility for adding error bars.. but i am getting only error bars for x values i.e. domain fluctuations but i want for the Range(y values) also. i have setted  setDrawXError(true); and setDrawYError(true); for the renderer.. also i want to control the error bar length.any idea how should i achieve it?

Comment: This is definitely a new question. You might want to check the demo and put together an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) in preparation.